# Import framework contain cpp files report error

Tags: c++, xcode, frameworks

I build a framework `libtest.framework`, which has those files:

```
//cfuncation.h
char* getcstring();

//cfuncation.c
#include <cfuncation.h>
char* getcstring() {
    return "123456";
}

//cppfuncation.h
#include <string>
std::string getcppstring();

//cppfuncation.cpp
#include "cppfuncation.h"
std::string getcppstring(){
    std::string rstr("This is cpp string");
    return rstr;
}
```

I export `cfuncation.h` and `cppfuncation.h` as public headr of framework. after build framework success.

```
//libtest.h generate by xcode
// In this header, you should import all the public headers of your framework using statements like #import <libtest/PublicHeader.h>
#import <libtest/cppfuncation.h>
#import <libtest/cfuncation.h>
```

I import framework in some app project file `AppDelegate.m` like`#import <libtest/cppfuncation.h>`

Howerer is will report error about
`Could not build module 'cpplibtest'` because `string' file not found` in `cppfuncation.h` code `#include <string>`

I did not import cpp files in `AppDelegate.m`,why will report this error?

Is there any way, i can build a framework which can contain cpp files headers and import the framework in `.m` files?

Comment: Few things other than C++ know how to use `std::string`. In fact, different implementations of C++ implement `std::string` differently, preventing you from using code compiled with one compiler with another. It's best to expose only Plain Old Data if you want a library to be widely used.

Comment: Is there a reason for using the C tag ?